# invoking command line java from java code accepting arguments

Tags: java

I am able to invoke a java class using below command line:

```
java -jar <my jar name>.jar -option1 <option> "<a string value>"
```

However, I want to invoke it from a another Java program.
The name of the main class is `XYZ`

I have imported the jar as a dependency in my project.

Comment: Do you want to launch it as a separate process, or just in-process? What happens if you just call the `main` method with the relevant arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That heavily depends on whether you want to launch it as a separate process or simply execute within the same one.

To kick it off in the same process, you could just call the main method:

```
String[] arguments = new String[]{"-option1", "<option>", "<a string value>"};
MyOtherMainClass.main(arguments);
```

To start it as a different process:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-jar", "<my jar name>.jar", "-option1", "<option>", "<a string value>");
Process process = pb.start();
int errCode = process.waitFor();
```

The second example was inspired by http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/processbuilder/java-lang-processbuilder-example/